# how to save email id in username mvc5 asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

This code seems to work fine in  my seed method.

```
 var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            FirstName = "abc",
            LastName = "abc",
            Email = "abc@yahoo.com",
            UserName = "amit"

        };

        success = idManager.CreateUser(user, "admin1");
```

but when i take Emailid in username. user is not created.
i am using MVC5 template in vs2012 and asp.net mvc5 identity .

Answer (score 1):

What version of ASP.NET Identity are you using?  I earlier versions, the username only allowed alphanumeric characters.

You can override it via the `UserValidator` property of the `UserManager` like this:

```
UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager){ AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Green this helped me. but do you think i should migrate my application to Asp.net identity 2.0?